# Probability that a specific event happened when an event happened in the group

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given that exactly 1 event happened within a group of 20 independent events, and knowing the probability of each event, how do I calculate the probability that a specific event happened?

Intuitively, I would say that it is $\frac{\text{Probability of Specific Event}}{\sum \text{Probability of each event}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: You should clarify:  do you mean that the events are jointly independent?  So that the probability of any specified group of the events happening is just the product of the probabilities of the events in that group?   That's what I assumed in my posted solution below, but perhaps you meant something else (like pairwise independence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{E_i\}$ be your events.

Let $X_i$ be the event "The event $E_i$ happens but none of the events $E_j$ with $i\neq j$ happen".  Then the independence of the $E_i$ tells us that $$P(X_i)=P(E_i)\times \prod_{j\neq i}(1-P(E_j))$$

Note that the $X_i$ are mutually exclusive, so the probability that exactly one of the $E_i$ happens is just $\sum P(X_i)$.

Your desired answer is then  $$\boxed {\frac {P(X_i)}{\sum P(X_i)}}$$